# Bulk psql data COPY from stdin in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, psql, node-postgres

I need to load the data in psql db time-to-time via a node app.
I'm using [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) package, which seems to be working fine with `INSERT` statements.

Since my db_dum is huge, I need to move to `COPY` statement in pg_dump (for better performance), but getting all kinds of error while trying to load the data with `pg` package in Node - This works find if I use command line `psql`

the psql dump file I have is huge which includes `COPY` statements like this:

```
COPY hibernate.address (id, create_timestamp, 
update_timestamp, street_address_line_1, street_address_line_2, city, state_code, postal_code, postal_code_suffix, country_code, latitude, longitude, updated_by_base_user_id) FROM stdin;
379173  2017-02-20 02:34:17.715-08  2018-01-20 08:34:17.715-08  3 Brewster St   \N  Phoenix AZ  17349   \N  US  \N  \N  719826
/.
```

Here's a pseudo code for the node app running the sql dump file:

```
const sqlFile = fs.readFileSync('data_dump.sql').toString();
const connectionString = `postgres://<user>:${PgPassword}@${pgIpAndPort}/<table>`;
const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
lient.connect();
client.query(sqlFile);
```

Here's a sample `pg_dump` command I use (which is for data-only - no schema):

```
pg_dump -U <user> --data-only --disable-triggers -n hibernate <table_name> > <dump_file.sql>
```

but it doesn't work when I'm trying to load the data via node app

I know `--column-inserts` would solve the problem, but that decreases the performance drastically.

So I'm looking for possible solutions for loading the data with `COPY tbl FROM stdin;` statement in the node app

Any suggestion/comments is appreciated.